# Java: Utilizar un operador ternario en condiciones más complejas

Tags: java, operador-ternario

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio que me piden crear un método para que se añadan una serie de animales a un recinto en el que el animal dependerá de un valor aleatorio entre el 0 incluido y el 10. Si el valor es menor que 3 el animal a añadir será Leon, si es mayor o igual que 3 y menor que 6 el animal será Pantera y si es igual o mayor que 6, será Tigre.

Luego hay unos valores de coordenadas x e y que serán aleatorios entre 0 y 100, el sexo dependerá también de un valor aleatorio de tipo boolean que si es true el valor será MALE y si es false FEMALE. Luego tendrán una edad de 0 y una salud de 100.

El código que he implementado es este:

```
    public void addAnimal() throws Exception {
        int tipo= (new Random()).nextInt(11);
        double x = (new Random()).nextDouble()*301;
        double y=(new Random()).nextDouble()*301;
        boolean sexo = (new Random()).nextBoolean();

        if (sexo == true) { 
            if(tipo < 3) { 
            Leon leon = new Leon (x, y, Gender.MALE, 0, 100, getRecinto(getRecintoSelected()));
            getFelinos().add(leon);
        }
        else if (3 <= tipo && tipo < 6) { 
            Pantera pantera = new Pantera (x, y, Gender.MALE, 0, 100, getRecinto(getRecintoSelected()));
            getFelinos().add(pantera );
        }
        else { 
            Tigre tigre = new Tigre (x, y, Gender.MALE, 0, 100, getRecinto(getRecintoSelected()));
            getFelinos().add(tigre);
        }
    }
        else { 
            if(tipo < 3) { 
            Leon leon = new Leon (x, y, Gender.FEMALE, 0, 100, getRecinto(getRecintoSelected()));
            getFelinos().add(leon);

        }else if (3 <= tipo && tipo < 6) { 
            Pantera pantera = new Pantera (x, y, Gender.FEMALE, 0, 100, getRecinto(getRecintoSelected()));
            getFelinos().add(pantera );
        }
        else {
            Tigre tigre = new Tigre (x, y, Gender.FEMALE, 0, 100, getRecinto(getRecintoSelected()));
            getFelinos().add(tigre);
        }
    }

}
```

Me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de simplificar el código mediante ternarios, no se muy bien como funcionan, las explicaciones que he encontrado por ahí son muy simples pero cuando hay algo mas complejo dentro de los if no se muy bien como seria.

Gracias

Un saludo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El operador ternario no simplifica el código. Algunos lo consideran incluso más difícil de leer, es por ello que normalmente se usan en expresiones simples.

A pesar de ello y para propósitos de demostración, en tu código podrías primero optimizar lo que tienes y luego pasarlo a ternatrios de la siguiente manera:

```
public void addAnimal() throws Exception {
    Random random = new Random();
    int tipo = random.nextInt(11);
    double x = random.nextDouble() * 301;
    double y = random.nextDouble() * 301;
    boolean sexo = random.nextBoolean();

    List felinos = getFelinos();
    Object recinto = getRecinto(getRecintoSelected());
    Gender gender = sexo ? Gender.MALE : Gender.FEMALE;
    felinos.add(tipo < 3 ? new Leon(x, y, gender, 0, 100, recinto) : tipo < 6 ? new Pantera(x, y, gender, 0, 100, recinto) : new Tigre(x, y, gender, 0, 100, recinto));
}
```

Si te resulta un poco difícil de entender, sugiero cambiar la indentación de la siguiente manera.

```
public void addAnimal() throws Exception {
    Random random = new Random();
    int tipo = random.nextInt(11);
    double x = random.nextDouble() * 301;
    double y = random.nextDouble() * 301;
    boolean sexo = random.nextBoolean();

    List felinos = getFelinos();
    Object recinto = getRecinto(getRecintoSelected());
    Gender gender = sexo ?
            Gender.MALE
            :
            Gender.FEMALE;
    felinos.add(
            tipo < 3 ?
                    new Leon(x, y, gender, 0, 100, recinto)
                    :
                    tipo < 6 ?
                            new Pantera(x, y, gender, 0, 100, recinto)
                            :
                            new Tigre(x, y, gender, 0, 100, recinto)
    );
}
```

Algunas optimizaciones en el código que tal vez no notaste:

- Creas 4 objetos de tipo `Random`, solamente necesitas uno.
- sexo ya es boolean, no neesitas compararlo con `true`.

Comment: muchas gracias Ruslan, me ha sido de mucha ayuda!

Comment: @Rubs Como muestra de agradecimiento, deberías de [aceptar la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) que te sirvió.

Comment: @MrDave1999 la paloma verde es para indicar que la respuesta resolvió el problema de quien pregunta. Adicionalmente están las flechas al lado de cada respuesta para indicar si fue útil (la flecha hacia arriba) o si no (flecha hacia abajo), al posicionar el mouse sobre los iconos obtendrás una descripción de para qué sirven.

Comment: @RuslanLópez Mi comentario no era para ti, sino, para el OP xD

Comment: @MrDave1999 uuuuuuuuy pues perdón por complementar tu comentario de como usar el sitio :P

Comment: Una cosilla que me está pasando al implementar el codigo que me habeis puesto, es que me añade los objetos duplicados, es decir al hacer un felinos.add y un new me crea con el new el felino en el recinto y luego me lo añade con el add, y por eso me sale duplicado. Entiendo que tengo que quitar el felinos.add pero en su lugar como lo pongo?? si lo quito sin mas me da error... como dejo solo el new Leon, etc etc?

Comment: nada chicos, le añadí un equals y solucionado. gracias

Answer (score 2):

> > ¿Cómo utilizaria aqui un ternario en Java?

Antes de usar el operador ternario, se debería de reducir el código creando un nuevo método con un parámetro.

**Ejemplo:**

```java
void addAnimal(Gender gd)
{
    int tipo = (new Random()).nextInt(11);
    double x = (new Random()).nextDouble()*301;
    double y=(new Random()).nextDouble()*301;
    if(tipo < 3)
        getFelinos().add(new Leon (x, y, gd, 0, 100, getRecinto(getRecintoSelected())));
    else if (3 <= tipo && tipo < 6) 
        getFelinos().add(new Pantera (x, y, gd, 0, 100, getRecinto(getRecintoSelected())));
    else 
        getFelinos().add(new Tigre (x, y, gd, 0, 100, getRecinto(getRecintoSelected())));
}
```

Y luego invocas el método de esta forma:

```java
public void assignSex() throws Exception 
{
     boolean sexo = (new Random()).nextBoolean();
     /* Aquí usamos un operador ternario simple */
    addAnimal(sexo ? Gender.MALE : Gender.FEMALE);
}
```

En el método `addAnimal` puedes usar operadores ternarios con múltiples condiciones, sin embargo, el código quedaría ilegible.